# Hooking up sub applications in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

I have two projects in asp.net core 2.1. One is the main web application, and the other is a sub-application. The sub-application is for the most part, independent; it only needs cookies from the main application.

I'm trying and failing to set up the two projects in my local dev environment, and I will also need to set up for live IIS Deployment in the future. I have both VS projects in the same VS Solution. In their project Debug settings page, I have them both set up to launch IISExpress with app URL as 'http://localhost:44305'. I have tried setting the subapp to 'http://localhost:44305/subapp' too, but when vs run, IISExpress complains that the port is already in use.

I have a web config for both apps. The very basic defaults for both. In the sub app, I have the extra line to remove the aspnetcore handler (as I found from searching).

```
<remove name="aspNetCore" />
```

In the sub app, i have also tried adding in startup.cs:

```
app.UsePathBase("/subapp")
```

The results I get from this setup running in vs locally is that on the base URL, it actually loads up my subapp instead of my main app (browser URL is localhost:44305). Fiddling with multiple settings seems to get me nowhere; either both apps fail to load completely, or one or the other app is inaccessible.

Is there any proper documentation out there for setting up multiple apps to work together locally and in IIS? Everything I seem to find is from pre-2.0.

Thank you for your help!

Edit:
I actually managed to get a fresh project working as subapp when deploying to IIS. To set up:

1. Make a new VS solution with two aspnetcore 2.1 web applications.
2. Add a web.config to sub application with following:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
       </handlers>
       <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\IISTestSubApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```
3. No web config for Main app.
4. Add .UseIISIntegration() to Program.cs CreateWebHostBuilder to both apps.
5. In Startup.cs Configure method for Subapp, add `app.UsePathBase("/subapp/");`
6. Deploy main app to a folder /Mainapp. Deploy sub app to /Mainapp/subapp.
7. Set up iis website for main app.
8. Right click on main app website in IIS and click Add Application. Add the subapplication with an alias '/Subapp'

That should be all you need. Some of the steps may not be necessary. I haven't fully tested which steps are 100% necessary.

Unfortunately, I still can't get it to work with IISExpress. I have my .vs/applicationhost.config file looks almost exactly like the IIS one, but when running both apps at the same time, i get errors saying that the port is already in use. I'm still trying a bunch of new things, so, we'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: That may get me a bit closer. Is there anything else you can provide info on? Like a correct webconfig? Should i use PathBase?

Comment: With your changes, i get my main app loading, but sub app gets HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Comment: I've retracted my submission as I've found there seem to be routing issues when using attribute routing. I'm not sure what else to suggest I'm afraid. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: @john yeah, i seem to almost get it working, but when i run the app, it switches the applicationpool to something else automatically.

Comment: I think a possible problem is in the webconfig of main app, where the aspnet handler is added. It is set to have path=' * ' and verb=' * '. Is it possible to ignore path '/subapp/'? I have tried adding specific paths for my main app, instead of *, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't how the arguments are formatted for this setting.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working now in IISExpress. Following the above steps for IIS first, for basic setup, include the following:

1. The subapp web.config file should look like this for IISExpress:

   ```
   <configuration>
       <system.webServer>
           <handlers>
           </handlers>
       <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\IISTestSubApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
       </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```
2. In your solution's .vs/config/applicationhost.config file, make sure your sites section looks like

   ```
   <site name="IISTest" id="2" serverAutoStart="true">
   <application path="/" applicationPool="IISTest AppPool">
     <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\IISTest\IISTest" />
   </application>
   <application path="/subapp" applicationPool="IISTest AppPool">
     <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\IISTest\IISTestSubApp" />
   </application>
   <bindings>
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:44301:localhost" />
   </bindings>
   </site>
   ```

It seems okay that both apps use a different application pool. Setting them the same gets overwritten when vs runs, for some reason.

3. Run only the main app from vs; Don't try to run sub apps as well. You will get port already taken error message.